# solidity transaction returns "unknown transaction" error in truffle console

Tags: solidity

I'm using ropsten test network to deploy my contracts. Contracts are deployed successfully but when i make a transaction in truffle console it returns:

```
Error: unknown transaction
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:186:7)
```

I start truffle console with:

`truffle console --network ropsten`

and for transaction:

`game.createPlayer("0x35f5164d941de22942288808C1E6e406ec148336", {from: "0x35f5164d941de22942288808C1E6e406ec148336"}).then(function(res){console.log(res)})`

Comment: Make sure you have the latest versions, check [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/721).

Comment: these are ther versions i'm using ```Truffle v4.0.6 (core: 4.0.6), Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js) and geth Version: 1.8.1-stable```

Comment: Well the fix was at Truffle `4.0.7` so you should try an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/721) issue you need to update to version `4.0.7` or higher to make it work.

Comment: upgrading truffle fixed the problem. now i'm having new issue ```Please check that the transaction:
    - satisfies all conditions set by Solidity `require` statements.
    - does not trigger a Solidity `revert` statement.
```

Comment: actually the contracts i'm using are not written by me so no idea about this one. i've tried with commenting the require statement in function but still it throws same error